# Getting reference to a Handler when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using a ScheduledExecutorService to run a Runnable periodically. In the Runnable I have registered a SensorEventListener. I noticed that the SensorEventListener callbacks gets called on the main thread rather than a thread from the thread pool of the ScheduledExecutorService. I want to handle the callbacks for the sensor events off of the main thread. It looks like I am able to pass a Handler object when calling registerListener() of the SensorManager class and the callbacks will be run on the thread that the Handler is from.

Is there a way to get a reference to a Handler of a ScheduledExecutorService?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard. A regular `ExecutorService` does not have a `Looper` and you can not have a `Handler` in such a thread.

A `Looper` is an infinite loop that dequeues and executes events. So if you schedule that your executor is blocked. You can probably implement your own executor based on the event handling of a Looper but I guess that's not what you want.

To use the sensor from the background you would create a `HandlerThread`. That's a background thread running a Looper and therefore it can have a `Handler`.

Small example

```
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("SomeNameHere");
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());

    mBackgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // I can do blocking network here.
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mHandlerThread.quitSafely();
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's what I ended up doing. Every 10 seconds I want to record 2 seconds worth of samples for SensorEvenListener. I ended up making a HandlerThread and getting a ref. to its Handler and passing that into SensorManager during registration. That HandlerThread then receives callback events and adds the values to a list. I kept my Scheduled ExecutorService which every 10 seconds runs a runnable that registers for sensor events, sleeps for 2 seconds (during this time the HandlerThread queues up values) then wakes up an unregisters for sensor events and caches values in db. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.myLooper());` in the background thread (Where your `ScheduledExecutorService` is running)  and then pass the instance to the `SensorManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Handler always 'handles' thing in the thread it was created, so just create a new one in your `ExecutorService`. Just use [default Handler constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#Handler())

Comment: And then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare happens